# Unable to assign (data: number) => void to (data: unknown) => void

Tags: typescript

```
type NumFunc = (data: number) => void;
type UnknownFunc = (data: unknown) => void;

declare let numFunc: NumFunc;
let unknomnFunc: UnknownFunc = numFunc
    ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Error:

```
Type 'NumFunc' is not assignable to type 'UnknownFunc'.
  Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

What??? I'm assigning number to unknown, why is it suddenly trying to assign unknown to number now?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwGJwHYGMoF4oAoAmAhsIQFxSqIBGEATgJTYB8UAbgPYCW+A3AFChIUAKqoA1qnYB3VCgzY8REuTQTpqRlhYdu-PvgjoANoVrQjEYBURz05eMjTp+Fq6skJZT8qLUzbCpSOGEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be a little more verbose: expand

```
let unknomnFunc: UnknownFunc = numFunc;
```

into

```
let unknomnFunc: UnknownFunc = x => numFunc(x);
```

We're taking an *unknown* argument `x` (because that's what `UnknownFunc` eats) and, without any type checking, use it as an argument of a `NumFunc`. Hence the protest. Do some type checking

```
let unknomnFunc: UnknownFunc = x => typeof x === 'number'
    ? numFunc(x)
    : void 0;
```

or declare "I know better" with type assertion

```
let unknomnFunc: UnknownFunc = x => numFunc(x as number);
```

Note that the errors also go away, when you replace *unknown* with *any*. That's the advantage of using *unknown*: you actually need to do *something* about type-unsafe operations, instead of charging "Leeroy Jenkins!"-style (as *any* allows you).

Comment: what does protest mean?

Comment: The error message.

Comment: Wow that's kind of trippy, UnknownFunc type is actually assignable to KnownFunc type, unlike how unknown type can never be assigned to known type

Answer (score 1):

Since `(data: unknown) => void` changes the parameter type to accept any type, the two function types aren't compatible.

```
numFunc('foo') // has type error
unknownFunc('foo') // does not have type error
```

If `unknown` was in the return type, it should be fine to change the type.